# Identify data inconsistency in a Tuple-like table

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a table that holds availability status for workers. Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Availability]
(
    [OID]                  BIGINT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LocumID]              BIGINT        NOT NULL,
    [AvailableDate]        SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [AvailabilityStatusID] INT           NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedAt]       TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Availability] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OID] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

And here is a result:

```
OID                  LocumID              AvailableDate           AvailabilityStatusID LastModifiedAt
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- ------------------
1                    1                    2009-03-02 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A8C
2                    2                    2009-03-04 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A8D
3                    1                    2009-03-05 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A8E
4                    1                    2009-03-06 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A8F
5                    2                    2009-03-07 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A90
6                    7                    2009-03-09 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A91
7                    1                    2009-03-11 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A92
8                    1                    2009-03-12 00:00:00     2                    0x0000000000201A93
9                    1                    2009-03-14 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A94
10                   1                    2009-03-16 00:00:00     1                    0x0000000000201A95
```

Now, the table has over 3mil record and I noticed that there are inconsistencies in my data. I need to somehow find rows where for any `[AvailableDate]`, the `[LocumID]` (regardless of how many,) must be unique. So, basically, a worker can have one of these `[AvailabilityStatusID] = 1, 2, 3, or 4` on one date. However, in this table, there are errors where a worker is entered twice or more against a `[AvailableDate]` with same `[AvailabilityStatusID]` or different `[AvailabilityStatusID]`

How can I detect these records?

Regards.

Comment: Which column represents a worker?

Comment: A worker is a Locum (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locum) in this system: [LocumID]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT LocumID, dt = AvailableDate
     FROM dbo.Availability
     GROUP BY LocumID, AvailableDate 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT a.OID, a.LocumID, a.AvailableDate, 
    a.AvailabilityStatusID, a.LastModifiedAt
 FROM x
 INNER JOIN dbo.Availability AS a
 ON x.LocumID = a.LocumID
 AND x.dt = a.AvailableDate
 ORDER BY a.LocumID, a.AvailableDate;
```

Once you clean this data up (not sure what your rule will be regarding which rows to keep), you should consider a unique constraint on (LocumID, AvailableDate). Here is how you would create the constraint (though you will not be able to create it until you have removed the duplicates):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Availability 
    ADD CONSTRAINT uq_l_ad 
    UNIQUE (LocumID, AvailableDate);
```

Of course now you will have new errors returned to your application (Msg 2627), since your current code clearly doesn't already check if a LocumID/AvailabilityDate combination already exists before adding a new one.

Comment: How can I have a combined unique constraint on (LocumID, AvailableDate)? I'd love to have such a constraint. Originally, the (LocumID, AvailableDate) was a composite PrimeryKey. But that was old ADO.NET project. I converted to ORM Linq and was facing issues as composite primers don't go very well.

Comment: I'm not sure what "don't go very well" means exactly, but if ORM Linq can't deal with unique constraints, there is something seriously wrong with either the technology or your specific implementation.

Comment: Ok. But how can I have a combined unique constraint on (LocumID, AvailableDate)? Regards.

Comment: Edited my answer, adding a sample of adding the constraint.

Comment: I already traced and fixed my code to delete any tuple(s) before adding new one. I deleted the duplicate rows by sorting the duplicates by ordering LastModified column (a timestamp) descending-wise. I have also added the constraint. Everything seems to be running perfectly now.

Comment: So you delete a row and insert a new one? I suggest that a conditional update would be better in the long run. YMMV.

Comment: No, I used the LastModified field to determine the latest row from the two or more duplicate inconsistent rows